# Network adapter issue (ONLY at university) - no networks available

Tags: wireless-networking

Recently I keep on encountering an odd issue with my wireless network adapter. When I go to my university (which has an eduroam network, among others), I usually get the network tooltip 'Not connected - No connections available'. This is not limited to the eduroam network, as there are a couple additional wireless networks here that aren't being detected either.

The issue is fixed temporarily by disabling and then re-enabling my network adapter, but sometimes recurs during the day, so it is not limited to the first boot of the day. The odd thing is, this ONLY happens at my university, not at home or my girlfriend's place. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing my network drivers, but to no avail. The issue seems limited to the adapter itself, as tethering with my android phone still works. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Computer information:

- HP Compaq 8510w
- 64-bit Windows 7 professional
- Intel Wireless Wifi Link 4965AGN network adapter

Comment: Have you spoken to your university's IT helpdesk? It may be that their network is broken, or it needs some unique configuration that none of us outside the university would possibly know.

Comment: I guess that would be a good idea. However, the laptop is quite old (6 years), a few of my friends have the same laptop but no issues, and our IT helpdesk is notoriously bad. But I'll give it a shot tomorrow!